# How to compose a S/MIME encrypted message in Rust?

Tags: email, rust, cryptography, public-key-encryption, smime

With so many crates available, I doubt the one for composing an encrypted S/MIME message would be missing. I'm aware of [pgp](https://crates.io/crates/pgp) which should handle PGP/MIME. I'm also aware of [lettre_email](https://docs.rs/lettre_email/) [emailmessage](https://crates.io/crates/emailmessage) and [mailparse](https://docs.rs/mailparse/) [mail-core](https://docs.rs/mail-core/) which could be used to compose a MIME e-mail message...

If there isn't one, I'm asking if someone already does this so I can copy cat and perhaps publish. Or else I'll be battling with it myself and will appreciate a good head start.

The goal is to encrypt messages at rest while stored on a mail server [Samotop](https://crates.io/crates/samotop). Knowing the recipient's public key, I should be able to wrap-encrypt any incoming message for that recipient so that only the user owning the key will be able to decrypt the message. It may well be that S/MIME is not the right fit for this but I'd fancy to make this usable with existing e-mail clients with S/MIME support.

To start off, I suppose there will be a symmetric key that encrypts the message and this key will be encrypted using asymmetric key for the recipient (potentially for multiple recipients) and included in the payload. Here is a [sketch of my ideas](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=330cb9939b990dceff941c2a4a27d899).

Random symmetric key is made:

```rust
    let mut key = [0u8; 32];
    SystemRandom::new().fill(&mut key).unwrap();
```

Content gets encrypted:

```rust
    // Sealing key used to encrypt data
    let mut sealing_key = SealingKey::new(
        UnboundKey::new(&CHACHA20_POLY1305, key.as_ref()).unwrap(),
        Nonces::new(5),
    );

    // Encrypt data into in_out variable
    sealing_key
        .seal_in_place_append_tag(Aad::empty(), &mut encrypted)
        .unwrap();
```

Symmetric key gets asymmetrically encrypted for the recipient:

```rust
    let enc_key = pub_key.encrypt(&mut rng, PaddingScheme::new_pkcs1v15_encrypt(), &key[..]).expect("failed to encrypt");
    assert_ne!(&key[..], &enc_key[..]);
```

Now comes the time to compose the encrypted MIME part... ideas? crates? reference implementations? [rfc8551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [figured this much](https://gitlab.com/BrightOpen/BackYard/Samotop/-/blob/e7098c3f16bb61e61f26458e8088669ce927b2f5/samotop-enc/src/main.rs). If I have to depend on openssl, I might just as well depend on it externally, running it as a child process. This will enable async io streaming as a bonus which doesn't seem to be supported by rust bindings ([yet?](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1387)).

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    async_std::task::block_on(main_fut())
}

async fn main_fut() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut sign = async_process::Command::new("openssl")
        .arg("smime")
        .arg("-stream")
        .arg("-in")
        .arg("test/msg")
        .arg("-sign")
        .arg("-inkey")
        .arg("test/my.key")
        .arg("-signer")
        .arg("test/my.crt")
        .kill_on_drop(true)
        .reap_on_drop(true)
        .stdout(async_process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;

    let mut encrypt = async_process::Command::new("openssl")
        .arg("smime")
        .arg("-stream")
        .arg("-out")
        .arg("test/enc")
        .arg("-encrypt")
        .arg("test/her.crt")
        .kill_on_drop(true)
        .reap_on_drop(true)
        .stdin(async_process::Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()?;

    let pipe = async_std::io::copy(
        sign.stdout.as_mut().expect("sign output"),
        encrypt.stdin.as_mut().expect("encrypt input"),
    );

    pipe.await?;

    println!("sign: {:?}", sign.status().await);
    println!("encrypt: {:?}", encrypt.status().await);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only ready solution I've found so far is the [openssl binding](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.30/openssl/pkcs7/struct.Pkcs7.html). It has a Pkcs7 struct that should be able to `encrypt()`, `sign()` and produce the mime part with `to_smime()`.

Here is a slightly modified [test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=708bb9166db6591e074f27bc10f5f91e) from the openssl repository:

```rust
        let cert = X509::from_pem(CERT)?;
        let mut certs = Stack::new()?;
        certs.push(cert.clone())?;

        let flags = Pkcs7Flags::STREAM;
        let message = b"secret stuff";

        let pkcs7 = Pkcs7::encrypt(&certs.as_ref(), message, Cipher::aes_256_cbc(), flags)?;

        let encrypted = pkcs7.to_smime(message, flags).expect("should succeed");
```